# source code for android native Video player API Lever 16

Tags: android, media-player

I need native media player for android for api level 16. What is the url for that ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp

Answer (score 2):

Use http://grepcode.com/ .Here you will get the entire source tree for android for different versions. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, a simple Google search would have sufficed...

That said, download this [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-sdk-reference-sea/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin)... it'll save you a lot of time searching for source code in the future.

Comment: A simple Google search takes you to this page, FWIW. I'm not sure why this question was closed (it's certainly a *real* question.)